# безопасность vpn

Tags: vpn

Недавно купил услугу VPN для свободного просмотра заблокированных сайтов. Очень удобно что можно выбрать сервер по желанию и скорость хорошая. Но к сожалению не могу найти ответ на простой вопрос по безопасности личных данных.

Если подключившись по этому VPN, я авторизуюсь в своем gmail/яндекс почте, интернет-банкинге или буду оплачивать кредитной картой на каком нибудь сайте это будет нормально?

Comment: Ваш вопрос должен быть адресован тому, у кого Вы приобретали услугу. Обычно продавец достаточно подробно расписывает на сайте преимущества своего товара, подчас касаясь тонкостей, в том числе и технического характера, которые могли бы быть интересны потенциальным покупателям, подкованным в соответствующих вопросах. Если по какой-либо причине аргументы продавца показались Вам неубедительными, сравните информацию, предоставляемую его конкурентами, благо таковых имеется в достатке.

Comment: @alexis031182 Если у вас есть vpn или был бы стали бы вы заходить в свою почту или интернет-банкинг через vpn? Просто хотелось узнать делают ли так люди и стоит ли вообще париться по этому поводу?

Comment: @alexis031182 сервис более менее раскрученный, не хотелось бы чтобы посчитали рекламой, прямую ссылку не буду оставлять, сервис называется hide . me , у них купил.

Comment: Сложно не согласиться с аргументацией в ответе @gecube. Ориентируйтесь на него.

Comment: В случае с сервисом Hola (тоже VPN) они почти наверняка используют Вашу машину с установленным их VPN-клиентом для предоставления услуг "анонимайзинга" для третьих лиц.
Т.е. разделите вопрос на два - 

1. Безопасна ли сама технология VPN?

2. Безопасно ли устанавливать некий непонятный софт к себе на компьютер (учитывая, что встроенных в операционную средств для подключения к чужим VPN полно)?

Comment: Как я понял лучше не использовать vpn для подобных целей. Спасибо за пояснения.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Добрый день!

Надо понимать, что используя сторонний VPN Вы с одной стороны защищаетесь от злоумышленников, которые могут перехватить Ваш трафик на участке от Вас до VPN сервера, но при этом Вы полностью доверяете *весь* свой трафик этому стороннему vpn-серверу. Т.е. его там могут перехватить. Или организовать Mitm-атаку. В зависимости от целей владельцев этого vpn.

Т.е. резюме:

- если Вам нужно спрятать свой IP адрес и открыть какой-либо ресурс и не хотите использовать прокси - vpn это нормальное решение.
- если Вы хотите обезопасить свой трафик от прослушки (например, выходите в сеть из инет-кафе), то vpn до *доверенного* сервера - тоже нормальное решение.

В противном случае - бессмысленные сложности.

Comment: Добрый день! Спасибо за ответ, теперь вся понятно.

Comment: Https ведь не даст осуществить mitm?

Comment: @Qwertiy ответ сложный. И да, и нет. Что я имею в виду. Если используется https трафик, то провайдер уже просто так вмешаться в него не сможет. НО! Например, в Казахстане всех обязали поставить корневой сертификат от государства и в этом случае любой государственный или окологосударственный провайдер, получается, может расшифровать трафик и его подменить.

Comment: @gecube, но если даже их обязали (хотя, я что-то не уверен - вроде бы откатили ту инициативу), то когда тебе придёт этот гос-сертификат в цепочке, тебя ж не обязывали и на твоём компе здесь цепочка будет невалидной. Или я что-то упускаю? А вообще, я довольно давно такой вопрос задавал - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/828435/178988 - может быть там подетальнее ответ напишешь, заодно и про остальные протоколы?

Comment: @Qwertiy Вам придется этот гос.сертификат добавить к исключениям или к корневым сертификатам на своем локальном компьютере, иначе весь интернет работать не будет (((

Comment: @gecube, или просто сменить страну в vpn ;)