# Какие данные могут перехватить владельцы VPN?

Tags: vpn

Если на компьютере или телефоне используется VPN, то какие данные станут доступны владельцам это VPN? Понятно что ip пользователя и весь http-трафик. А какая часть https-трафика? И что насчёт других протоколов?

Comment: А о каких других протоколах речь? Вообще им будет доступен весь трафик вопроса-ответа, но шифрование решает такие вопросы. Чего-то сверхествественного они не получат.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов наверно имелись ввиду ftp, rpd и тд. И да, vpn сможет узнать ваш логин/пароль от ftp (не путать с sftp),  а также прочитать пересылаемый config.php

Comment: @DiDex ну как сказать узнать, он сможет узнать все, весь трафик, если тот не шифруется, а если шифруется ему будут доступны но он не сможет расшифровать даже `config`.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов безусловно, (Привет телеграм)

Comment: для https - как минимум, dns-запросы могут тоже пойти через vpn. траффик не расшифруют, но факт посещения сайтов косвенно отследить могут.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, имеется в виду трафик игр, а также влияние VPN на p2p-соединения. dns - да. И вообще всё, что обычно есть на компе. Т. е. по максимуму, что теоретически можно достать.

Comment: @DiDex, а что с телеграмом?

Comment: @PashaPash, а разве у https адрес сайта (не страницы) не посылается?

Comment: @Qwertiy [наверняка посылается](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

Comment: В общем случае, VPN-серверу будет доступен весь отправляемый от лица клиента трафик, поэтому вопрос эквивалентен "что из моего трафика доступно моему провайдеру", VPN только подменяет "провайдера" на "владельца VPN-сервера". Более того; некоторые провайдеры доступ к интернет дают как раз через VPN, в каковых случаях "подмены" как бы и нет :)

Comment: @D-side, нет, надо вопрос сводить к "что может понять", потому что да, трафик весь, но расшифровать-то можно не всё.

Comment: @Qwertiy подчёркиваю, не "какой трафик", а "что **из** трафика". Повторюсь, VPN тут ни при чём.

Comment: @Qwertiy HTTPS - этот шифрование трафика между тобой и web сервером. Но до подключения к сайту тебе нужно узнать его IP адрес.  Это делается обычным udp запросом к dns серверу. dns вообще поддерживает шифрование, но оно необязательное. Чтобы сделать его обязательным со стороны клиента - нужны дополнительные действия (dnscrypt поставить и настроить в случае винду,  например)

Comment: @PashaPash, ну можно ответ? ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Т.е. речь именно про недоверенный VPN.

Чисто гипотетически владельцы недоверенного VPN могут увидеть:

- для любого протокола - адреса и порты конечных серверов.
- для любого незашифрованного протокола (HTTP, FTP...) - сделать снимок трафика и вытащить оттуда все пользовательские логины/пароли
- дополнительно - раскрыть сайты, которые посещает пользователь, через утечку данных по DNS (по умолчанию DNS незашифрован + некоторые провайдеры запросы к внешним DNS перехватывают и подсовывают свои записи). Сейчас, конечно, есть движение в направлении DoT и DoH, но до полноценного внедрения дело пока не дошло.
- чтобы внедриться в зашифрованный трафик HTTPS - нужно либо использование украденных и валидных сертификатов (никто не проверяет сертификат на принадлежность к какой либо организации, т.к. это противоречит идее Domain Validation).

Я уж не говорю о том, что если на компьютере открыты какие-либо порты с какими-либо сервисами, то владельцы VPN (и при определенных настройках - другие пользователи VPN) могут просканировать компьютер на предмет уязвимых сервисов и провести на них атаку (через переполнение буфера и т.п).