# Админы VPN шпионят за другими моими VPN-коннектами?

Tags: vpn

Работаю на разных заказчиков и для доступа к их внутренним ресурсам подключаюсь через VPN используя софтовые клиенты (Soft Ether, Cisco Any Connect и какой-то no-name самописный клиент).

> Вопрос №1: Видят ли администраторы VPN - по каким сайтам я хожу со своего личного компьютера

Чтобы проверить, я провёл два эксперимента:

1. Выполнил команду tracert до google.com до подключения и после подключения. Результат одинаковый в обоих случаях (количество прыжков, время прохождения и IP не изменились).
2. Проверил на нескольких сайтах мой IP - везде он совпадает с реальным, даже при подключении сразу ко всем VPN.

Второй эксперимент не очень объективный - думаю, что админы VPN могут настроить так, чтобы при проксировании трафика пробрасывался мой реальный IP, тогда будет ложное ощущение, что трафик не контролируется.

Первый эксперимент даёт представление по какому маршруту идёт сетевой пакет. Если я не ошибаюсь, то адрес VPN-сервера в нём не участвует. Это добавляет понимания, однако, чтобы найти исчерпывающий ответ на свой вопрос - я попробовал разобраться и поискать информацию в различных источниках, но к сожалению, так и не нашёл. Более того, в процессе исследования возник ещё один вопрос, который я задал ниже.

Мне удалось выяснить, что есть несколько видов VPN подключения - одни используются для соединения с интернетом или с локальными сетями, другие - для шифрования трафика и скрытия реального IP.

Это информация поверхностная и не совсем то, что я хотел - продолжил поиск уже по теме "настройка VPN" и выяснил, что если настраивать подключение вручную, то технически нужно создать виртуальный туннель и прописать до него статические маршруты. Выходит, что в случае, когда мы используем софтовый клиент подключения к VPN (Soft Eather, Cisco Any Connect, etc), то эти манипуляции производит софт. Но как понять, какой вид подключения и какие маршруты они создают? Так же неясно, ретранслируются ли какие-нибудь широковещательные TCP пакеты моей сетью в сети других VPN?

> Вопрос №2: Могут ли администраторы VPN №1 видеть ресурсы, которые мне стали доступны после подключения к VPN №2?

Пока я не уверен какой траффик могут видеть администраторы VPN, то на локальной машине создал несколько виртуалок. В каждой виртуалке необходимое рабочее окружение и только одно настроенное VPN-соединение. Думаю, что в таком случае траффик будет видно лишь тот, который генерируется на стороне виртуалки, а внешний трафик с железного компьютера уже к ним не попадёт. Это решение временное и требует много ресурсов моего локального компьютера, поэтому если можно как-то иначе - я буду рад узнать ваше мнение. Спасибо.

Comment: Неважно какой вид соединения, владелец VPN в любом случае видит весь трафик и может управлять им, иначе VPN просто не смог бы работать

Comment: Если к владельцу VPN нет доверия, то всё равно нужно использовать дополнительные слои шифрования, вроде HTTPS или SSH

Comment: «до каких хостов они прописали свои маршруты» — это нужно спрашивать у них, ну или смотреть в настройках своей ОС какие маршруты прописались

Comment: @andreymal Если правильно понял, то весь траффик - это только в том случае, если он соответствует определённому правилу, которое настраивается при создании VPN. В противном случае, если траффик не соответствует правилу, то созданный туннель не задействуется

Comment: если под правилами вы имеете в виду маршруты, то да

Comment: какая у вас ОС?

Comment: @RomanKonoval Windows 10

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/828435/178988

Comment: @andreymal, но если на компьютере установлена программа, она вполне могла при установке поставить корневой сертификат и расшифровывать https так же, как это делает fiddler. Теоретически от этого мог бы защитить HTTP Public Key Pinning, но вроде он уже deprecated. Ну и есть вариант, что для таких сайтов перехват отключен. Так что надо сертификаты проверять руками и смотреть, что там за цепочка.

Comment: @Qwertiy или пользоваться Firefox, который даже на доверенные, но неизвестные ему корневые сертификаты всё равно слегка ругается :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо за дополнительную информацию. Наталкивает на мысль, что, возможно, VPN-клиент и VPN-соединения отличаются друг от друга - одни перенаправляют весь локальный траффик, а другие - только траффик на указанные хосты. Всё-таки, мой вопрос отличается от указанного по ссылке.

Comment: @andreymal, а ему нельзя программно прописать левый серт в доверенные? Только руками потыкав да-да, я согласен?

Comment: @Qwertiy можно, но внутри зелёного замочка всё равно будет плашка, что Mozilla не в курсе о таком сертификате (хотя раз уж на то пошло, можно и пропатчить браузер, чтобы скрыть эту плашку, хех)

Comment: @hwak, возможно что угодно, но что конкретно он делает, никто ж не знает. К тому же, мы вроде обсуждаем худший вариант, а не лучший? Кстати, посмотри на сайте свой ip - в случае прямого соединения и прогона через vpn он будет различаться.

Comment: @Qwertiy проверил - на сайтах указан мой родной IP. Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @hwak, если сайты показывают "родной" адрес, значит, с неплохой долей вероятности, вы не используете VPN для доступа к этим сайтам.